# Why does sandbox app also need secure canvas url?

Tags: https, sandbox, facebook-canvas

I already enabled sandbox mode, but still not allowed to save changes without https canvas url. This makes it a lot harder to test any canvas page related changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just enter the same URL as your app, and add in `https` instead of `http`. It should still use the HTTP URL providing you are using Facebook over a non-secure connection.